# How to properly bundle install on a Ruby on Rails web-app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bundler

I am trying to run `bundle install` while in the base dir of a git cloned Ruby on Rails repo on an Ubuntu subsystem (on Windows 10). But I keep getting this error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching git@bitbucket.org:wishartlab/wishart
Forbidden
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
Retrying `git clone --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet -- git@bitbucket.org:wishartlab/wishart /home/sukanta/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/wishart-32827d90c8420e2e6b6bd9330b841cfef2863a8c` at /home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web due to error (2/4):
Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet -- git@bitbucket.org:wishartlab/wishart /home/sukanta/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/wishart-32827d90c8420e2e6b6bd9330b841cfef2863a8c` in directory /home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web'
Retrying `git clone --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet -- git@bitbucket.org:wishartlab/wishart /home/sukanta/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/wishart-32827d90c8420e2e6b6bd9330b841cfef2863a8c` at /home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web due to error (3/4):
Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet -- git@bitbucket.org:wishartlab/wishart /home/sukanta/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/wishart-32827d90c8420e2e6b6bd9330b841cfef2863a8c` in directory /home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    Retrying `git clone --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet -- git@bitbucket.org:wishartlab/wishart /home/sukanta/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/wishart-32827d90c8420e2e6b6bd9330b841cfef2863a8c` at /home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web due to error (4/4):
Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet -- git@bitbucket.org:wishartlab/wishart /home/sukanta/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/wishart-32827d90c8420e2e6b6bd9330b841cfef2863a8c` in directory /home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web'
Git error: command `git clone --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet -- git@bitbucket.org:wishartlab/wishart /home/sukanta/.rbenv/versions/2.6.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/wishart-32827d90c8420e2e6b6bd9330b841cfef2863a8c` in directory /home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/home/sukanta/phastest/phaster-web'
```

I have added my ssh key to Bitbucket and have the rights to the repo so that should not be a problem.